# Unable to install gem 'pg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, pg

I am trying to bundle install a ruby-on-rails project that I cloned from bitbucket and it's getting terminated while installing pg, so I tried installing pg separately.

When I run gem install pg -v '0.20.0', the following logs are shown

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/ext
D:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=D:/Ruby31-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --enable-windows-cross
        --disable-windows-cross
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/pg-0.20.0/mkmf.log   

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-0.20.0 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/pg-0.20.0/gem_make.out
```

How do I fix this ?

- windows 10
- hyper terminal

Comment: Did you read the references log?

Comment: I just solved it now using gem install pg -v '0.20.0' -- --with-pg-config='D:\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_config' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command:

```
gem install pg -v '0.20.0' -- --with-pg-config='D:\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_config'
```

This helped where you can put any version required instead of 0.20.0 and the path to pg_config according to your local system.